# Is it better to have multiple tables with the same primary key or one big data table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ms-access

So there is one primary key so far used for IDs of locations.

Currently there are multiple tables (sheets) in Excel for the following

- Events (Location ID, Date, Title, Description)
- Animals (Location ID, Species, Name, Population)
- Restrictions (Location ID, Permits, Zone)

Is the above bad practice? From what I have read online you should not use the same primary key across multiple tables.

How should the tables be structured to follow "best practices", have it be one big database table or is it fine to leave in multiple tables?

Comment: What do you think the primary keys are in your "tables", and why?

Comment: The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a table. So from my understanding each unique identifier would be the "Location ID", no? Please educate or correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If that is so, you can visit each location only once, and each location can only have a single species. Whether it's true or not I cannot tell, as you don't describe your business requirements.

Comment: I should have mentioned and will update the question. In the current state and likely in the future, each site will only have one event, animal/mascot, and restriction. 

Let's say I would like to introduce new animals, how should the structure or primary key change to suit?

Thank you for following up and asking for more questions I really appreciate it. This isn't really for business, but a personal fun learning experience for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per mustaccio's comment, when you have the same `PrimaryKey` defined in each of your `Tables`, that then guarantees a one-to-one relationship is enforced between each `Table`. In other words, based on the schema of your `Tables` provided in your question, you won't ever be able to have more than one Animal at one Event, or more than one Restriction for a specific Animal, etc. They all share the same `unique` Location ID.

If that meets your needs then your design is ok.
But if you want to be able to have multiple Animals at multiple Events with varying Restrictions for different locations etc, then you might be better off with the following design:

Add a fourth `Table` called Locations with the Location ID `PrimaryKey`.

Remove the Location ID `PrimaryKey` (and `unique constraint`) from all the other `tables` and instead create a `ForeignKey` relationship between it and your Locations `table` on Location ID.

Add a new `unique PrimaryKey` field to the Events, Animals, Restrictions `tables` with the appropriate names (e.g. Event ID for the Events `table`, Animal ID for the Animals `table`, etc).

And to directly answer your main question, it's better to keep these as separate `Tables`. That is called [database normalization](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) and is important for query efficiency and elimination of unnecessary data redundancy, but most importantly improved data integrity too. In general, separation of concerns should be split into separate `Tables`.

Comment: As one new to SQL, I really appreciate this thought out answer.

Comment: @WhoIsCarlo Glad you found it helpful!